# SSRS sort by last date available

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have columns with Name, Description and a Message. In order to see these columns in ssrs a date filter is applied. However when the date is short i get an error. Error: Execution terminated by the provider because a resource limit was reached. My question is: Is it possible to reduce the data filter to the last date that exist in the database. In this way the data filter could be applied to the last existing date in the database, and then the error would be eliminated.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit1:

Time stamp             | Name      | Description | Message  |

11/12/2011 10:50:51 AM | EBKBH 2349| Pump        |Functional|

01/08/2012 10:50:51 AM | ZDFWH 2989| Sensor      | Closed   |

And lets say that 1/08/12 is the last date in the database, but in the filter I select a date between 01/01/13 - 02/02/13 then the app runs for really long and then it gives me the error I mentioned earlier

Comment: Please edit your question and make it more clear. "I have different columns that I retrieve after using a data filter." - which filter you use and where? "However when the time period is set on a short period the service is running for ages and then returns an error." exactly which error are you getting and from which service? Also posting an example of query will help to give you answer.

Comment: Tried to edit, if it's still not clear i will try to find a way to provide an example.

Comment: SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(Server,
  ''
  SELECT * FROM Table
  WHERE ObjectName IN 
  (SELECT Name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT FROM DBServer"MyTable"
  WHERE LOCATION = ''''Name1'''' AND SOURCE = ''''Name2'''') AND TIMESTAMP >= '''' ' + **@StartDate** + ' '''' AND TIMESTAMP < '''' ' + **@EndDate** + ' ''''

Comment: @Roman Badiornyi do you think an if statement in the query could solve the issue? Something like 
IF EndDate< **@startingDate** 
RETURN Error

Comment: please provide some screenshots, in addition - does the date is also a column in the table you are talking about ?

Comment: I also can't get you. Why you get error when date is short? What you are mean "short"? Small date range? If so, then I suppose that records count should be smaller than with long date range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not getting why you are doing Openquery when you can select multiple DataSources in SSRS.

I would do something simpler than that.

1. Set up a datasource for your table date, and another one if your actual data is elsewhere.
2. Set up a dataset, call it 'MaxDate', for the last date with something like:

   ```
   Select Max(Date) as MaxDate
   From (tableName)
   ```

   This gives you the max date for the whole table which it sounds like you want.
3. Set up a parameter that gets this dataset in 2.  By selecting the parameter to use the 'get values from query'.  Select it to use the MaxDate as the id and the label.
4. Now set up a dataset for your main query however you like and do the predicate like:

   ```
   Where dt between @Start and @MaxDate
   ```
5. You can set up the @Start parameter with whatever you want for the date values but the @MaxDate is bound to a max date you specified.

** Optional: You set another Date field as @End and just default the value of the @MaxDate to it if you want the flexibility to not HAVE TO use the @MaxDate.  You would simply create a third variable, @End, and then in the 'Default Values' pane choose 'specify values'.  Hit the 'Fx' (expression) button, and then choose Parameters!MaxDate.Value and this would DEFAULT it to the max date.  But you could choose a prior date as well.

I usually set up most of my reports up with defaults for dates from a shared dataset to keep them all running on set date ranges.

Comment: Btw the reason I am using Openquery is because I need to connect to a linked server as well. Basically I have a table from where using the primary key I select multiple columns from a table on a linked server.

Comment: You could connect to two datasets seperately unless you have to do them in the same query.  Keep in mind with SSRS you may also create a report as an object, reference a completely different dataset and report.  Then call that separate report in your main report as a 'subreport'.   Subreports can even be nested in cells of table objects.  Keep that in mind as it may not fit your needs here but it may in some cases when you are working with presentation of multiple datasets at once.